# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at com.businessobjects.bcm.BCM.<clinit>(BCM.java:1144)

Tags: java, jboss7.x, business-objects, bcm

I am trying to deploy a war file which creates `IEnterpriseSession`. I am able to successfully run on Tomcat, but when I run it on JBoss, I get the below error at this step `sessionMgr.logon(trustedPrincipal);`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.businessobjects.bcm.BCM.&lt;clinit&gt;(BCM.java:1144)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.TrustedPrincipal.getRandomString(TrustedPrincipal.java:252)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.TrustedPrincipal.getPassword(TrustedPrincipal.java:195)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon_aroundBody22(SessionMgr.java:850)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon(SessionMgr.java:1)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon_aroundBody20(SessionMgr.java:818)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon_aroundBody21$advice(SessionMgr.java:512)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon(SessionMgr.java:1)
```

I tried with the solution mentioned in the [ExceptionInInitializerError - JBoss 7.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659655/exceptionininitializererror-jboss-7-0-2), but I still couldn't get through.

I was digging more into the error and this is where I am stuck

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: An internal FIPS 140 self-verification test has 
                                        failed.  Algorithm HMAC has been disabled
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.f.ug.d(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.f.ug.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.f.nd.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.f.nd.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.jsafe.CryptoJ.isFIPS140Compliant(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.bcm.internal.BcmRsaLib.initialize(BcmRsaLib.java:214)
    at com.businessobjects.bcm.internal.BcmRsaLib.<clinit>(BcmRsaLib.java:289)
```

Can someone help me to get it working on JBoss?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExceptionInInitializerError - JBoss 7.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659655/exceptionininitializererror-jboss-7-0-2)

Comment: Have you checked [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/203131) out ? It's similar but not identical to the linked question's most upvoted answer.

Comment: Hi @Aaron I have tried that too but no luck